# How to give the bevel emboss effect to mesh

Tags: extrude, bevel

[image] I have created svg file and imported in blender. I have 2 layers named front and back. Back layer i have extruded but front layer i want to bevel with the reference image (gold). I want front layer to get that effect. How to achieve and what settings i have to make to get effect. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Answer your question dude...

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu if you have the answer plz go ahead